# Cannot install a generator with yo

Tags: yeoman, yo

I am discovering [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/generators/) and I try to install a simple generator shown in yeoman's "Getting Started" section..

I installed npm then yo and bower like explained in the documentation :

```
npm install -g yo bower
```

When I try to install generator-webapp and generator-spring (`sudo npm install -g generator-webapp`), I get this output in both cases:

```
[...]
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/es6-iterator
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/es6-symbol
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package yo does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-mocha@0.1.6 wants yo@>=1.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-spring@0.1.2 wants yo@>=1.0.0-rc.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-webapp@0.5.1 wants yo@>=1.2.0

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-12-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "generator-webapp"
npm ERR! cwd /home/adenoyelle
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/adenoyelle/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Hence, I looked at yo version's :

```
~ [ sudo npm update -g yo 
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
~ [ yo -version
1.1.2
```

So, I have a few questions :

1. Why Yo's version is stuck to 1.1.2 (It seems that a version 1.3.3 exists)
2. Why does Yo also try to get generator-webapp when I ask generator-spring? generator-spring only requires Yo 1..0.0-rc.1 so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It's happened to me as well. I have no idea the reason why it is having some issues, even trying to install any dependency by separated.

Anyway, what I have done to solve this after spending some hours installing, reistalling, cleaning caches, googling and so on and so forth was basically updating nodejs.

I am on Linux Mint, then Ubuntu and Debian should be the same or similar.

To sum up,

Install nvm before

```
nvm ls-remote
nvm install 0.12.0
nvm use 0.12.0
node -v
npm install -g generator-webapp
npm install -g yo bower grunt-cli gulp
```

I would recommend to use nvm for updating node, you can follow this guide or tutorial

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server#how-to-install-using-nvm

After that, I was able to install yo and its dependencies without any problem.

By the way I chose version node v0.12.0

Hope this help